# Is there a way to see GUID for a metadata column in a list without using a SharePoint Designer?

Tags: managed-metadata, column, guid

Is there a way to see GUID for a metadata column in a list without using a SharePoint Designer?

I could have used SharePoint Designer but I can't because the customer has turned it off for some reason. I know with SharePoint designer is possible but I'm wondering if is there any other way as I don't have rights to use a designer.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you do not have access to the SP server, in which case you could use SharePoint Manager to view the list column details, or use the Server object model to retreive the information.

You could use PowerShell to connect to SP using web services (client object model) to get list/column information too.  This would be using /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx web service.

Unfortunately unlike list GUIDS, you can't view browser source to view the column GUIDS, SharePoint uses the column names as argument values.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the GUID of the term in a column then you could find this by inspecting the html of an edit form with this column populated it. The value is in a **hidden input field** above the div column. I think you'd also be able to find this by browsing the **hidden taxonomy list** via the url *sitecollection/taxonomyhiddenlist*

Answer (score 0):

The GUID information for each and every metadata column is available in the

```
<siteUrl>/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx
```